# Customizing text in the standard Wix dialogs

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm making use of the Wix standard dialogs. How do I customise the text of the messages displayed?

For example, in the License Agreement page, I want to change the text "I accept the terms in the License Agreement" to "I acknowledge and accept the terms of the above agreement."

---

Related:
[How can I set at runtime the text to be displayed in VerifyReadyDlg ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791041)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Add a new Localisation file to my Votive project (ie my Visual Studio Wix project) - right-click, Add -> New Item... -> Wix Localisation file
2. Since I was customising the english text, I made sure the Culture attribute in the file said *en-US*
3. Added String elements for each element that I wanted to customise. E.g.

   ```
   <WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
       <String Id="WelcomeEulaDlgLicenseAcceptedCheckBox">I accept the terms of the above Agreement</String>
   </WixLocalization>
   ```
4. To determine the Ids of the strings I needed to override, I looked in the [WixUI_en-us.wxl](http://wix.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wix/wix/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl?revision=1.12&view=markup) file from the Wix source code. In some cases it was helpful to refer to the [source code of the individual dialogs](http://wix.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wix/wix/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/) to find which strings were used where.
5. Last point to note is that when you add a localisation file to your project, Wix starts outputing the msi files in subfolders named for the culture in the localisation file. E.g. mine were written to *\bin\Debug\en-u*s rather than *\bin\Debug*\

Comment: You can also use Orca to determine the Ids of the strings.

Comment: Important note, if you get **many errors** like `The localization variable !(loc.MyVariable) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.`
This happens, when you add a `*.wxl` file with a **culture, which doesn't exist in the UIExtension**. For example `en-GB`. In the WiX toolkit repository you can check for existing `*.wxl` files. ([here are the files](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib))

Comment: Good steps and useful links. See also this WiX tutorial page [How To: Make your installer localizable](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/make_installer_localizable.html).

Answer (score 6):

The chapter *Advanced WiX Topics -> Wix UI Dialog Library -> Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets* in the WiX documentation (wix.chm) has all the information on customising the UI dialogs, including the text.  There's also a topic on customising the UI in the WiX tutorial at http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/ .

If you do find you need to override more of WiX's default behaviour, the best way to start is to download the sources ( e.g. from http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.1030.0/wix35-sources.zip ): all the UI dialogs are in src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib, and will give you an insight into how it works.