# Reference for possible String ID's in WixLocalization?

Tags: wix

I am finding WIX to be nearly impenetrable.

I want to customize the text in various dialogs in the WixUI_FeatureTree.

I've seen [Customizing Text in the standard WIX Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723840/customizing-text-in-the-standard-wix-standard-dialogs), so I get the basic idea that I need a .wxl file, and I need to fill it with `<String ...>` elements.   But what Id's are available?

**Q1**:  where is the list of Id's for the various supported strings?

---

side comment:
Am I just looking in the wrong place?  I'm looking in the Wix doc, but nothing is obvious.  Figuring out this Wix stuff is much harder than I expected it to be.  It is not easily discoverable, at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have to download the WiX source code, and go through it's WXL files, find the text you want to override, then use that ID.

The code is the reference.

Hang in there.  WiX/MSI starts to make sense at about your fourth installer.

Comment: Thank you.  You were right, the doc is not helpful.  The code is indispensable.