# WIX Dialog change property text value

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6, wix-extension

Can I change the Text properties of buttons on existing controls?

The code below doesn't do the trick

```
<Publish Dialog="FeaturesDlg" Control="Install" Property="Text" Value="Next" />    1</Publish>
```

I'd like to avoiud creating a custom dialog if at all possible.

Comment: I think it is only possible to create your own dialog, its very easy to do as the Wix sources has all the code there for you.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723840/customizing-text-in-the-standard-wix-dialogs

Comment: All dialogs are custom, and all actions are custom. It's just that some of them are given to you, ready to use. If the shoe doesn't fit, pick another.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in the WiX UI should all use loc identifiers. Thus, you should be able to override the text using a .wxl file. In WiX v3.6+ you can override control sizes, as per: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/